Console log not printing response from the server via fetch()
I am using a script to send transactions from my card website to localhost, which is accurately receiving it and also successfully sends a json response but after that console.log  isn't displaying it at all. I can check the response on network tab in dev tools but just curious what's the reason for not printing json response.
async function sendData(username, transactions) {
  let apiUrl = "http://localhost:3100/api";
  let postOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    redirect: "follow",
    referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, transactions }),
  };

  try {
    let response = await fetch(apiUrl, postOptions);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Response status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    let serverMessage = await response.json();
    console.log(serverMessage);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}


I even tried without async as following but still nothing printed.
function sendData(username, transactions) {
  let apiUrl = "http://localhost:3100/api";
  let postOptions = {
    method: "POST",
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    redirect: "follow",
    referrerPolicy: "no-referrer",
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, transactions }),
  };

  fetch(apiUrl, postOptions)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((msg) => console.log(msg))
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
}

One Clarification:
When I run the same code (with some triggering front end of course) in a JS injector chrome extension (e.g; scripty), it then prints the response, but not when I call it manually in console.

are you saying that neither console.log(serverMessage); nor console.log(error.message); executes in the browser? Are you sure you haven't filtered out console.log's? Or perhaps the server response isn't being sent properly. What do you observe in the browser network tab regarding this request?

One of console.log(serverMessage) or console.log(error.message) must get executed and print something (assuming your response body is not an empty string). If you don't see any of this, it's not because of your code but because of your browser settings.

Neither console statements print anything. I haven't filtered out console.log as it's perfectly working for the rest of the code executed with it; for example; if I write console.log("sending to server...") before calling sendData() it does print. In network tab, I see full json response from the server as expected.

You did not show the code calling sendData. I could be broken, not the code you've presented.

@SergeyAKryukov Actually, the call to sendData doesn't really matter (as long as it's there). Because as soon as this method is called (and OP claim they can see the request in the network inspector) there has to be some sort of output ...

I just tested it with a simulated server side through my URL where the server side responds with some JSON content.
The only modifications to your code were: 1) this URL, 2) I added the call to sendData at the end: sendData("user", null);.
Everything works, and it works with your original asynchronous variant. The line console.log(serverMessage); outputs exactly the test JSON string prescribed on the server side. I tested your code with node.js.
So, the problem is not in the code you've presented in your question. The possible problems may lie in wrong observations: you could have stopped the server on your localhost, the server part could be broken between your tests, the piece of code calling sendData could be modified between your tests and broken, or you could have presented not exactly the same JavaScript as you've been executing. Please double-check everything, and your script should work again.
Added:
From the comments to this answer, it looks like they confirm my conclusion that the problems were caused not by the script you've presented in your question, and the script actually works. The issue could be, as I mentioned, wrong observation, in particular, some problems with the debugging environment, such as UI issues. In some cases, the console.log actually works, but, for some reason, you cannot see the output on the console. It is not related to the script itself.I provided some debugging recommendations in my comments to this answer — in particular, one reliable technique is doing server-side logging.

Thanks for the answer. Everytime I call sendData() I do get the expected json response in network tab. Also I have a console.log() in NodeJS server printing the received transactions as expected and saves them to MongoDB perfectly. Everything is executed perfectly excetp the console.log(). It working perfectly for you is exactly how it should behave, but maybe some website or Chrome restrictions. idk

@Hamid Ali: I don't think so. I am using Chromium-based browser (V8 + Blink) and Apache, all the setup is the most usual. Another step would be the development of a sample code with both the server and client side, as simple as possible, just a few lines each. Besides, you need to run the client side under the debugger and simply inspect serverMessage before the console output.  It could be just your environment. Instead of console.log you should better write this content of serverMessage to a server log. You could post the update to your question then.

I don't know how you use your debugging environment for the client side. What is it? Just Chrome development tools? Does it output some test string before sendData? I, for example, use VSCode, multiplatform, highly recommended, can debug both client and server parts, and so on... On the client side, it uses Chrome's debug API.
It looks like you don't have a problem with your code, once you say it correctly updates your database. As I said, it could be an observation problem, and some problem of the debugging environment also classifies as wrong observation.

@Hamid Ali — Another question: did you execute that script under the debugger step-by-step between the line let response = await fetch(apiUrl, postOptions); and the line let serverMessage = await response.json();? After the second line, you had to inspect the content of serverMessage...

I use Chrome dev tools console because I have to be logged in to my card website in the browser to scrap the transactions from it before sending to server to save it to db.

@Hamid Ali — and one unrelated note: I can see 4 mistakes, absolutely not critical and irrelevant, but this is wrong coding: you have 4 let keywords in your code, while all 4 of them should be const. Even the objects you need to modify: const does not prevent that.

@Hamid Ali — “I use Chrome dev tools...”. I tried them directly, and they basically work but... so-o-o inconvenient. You need a humane environment, it matters a lot. Chrome and compatible browsers, MS Edge and Mozilla provide debugging APIs used by the IDEs.
